# Sorting Variables in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

If I have 4 integer variables in python and I want to sort them from highest to lowest value, and output the highest, how would I approach this?

Comment: you need to show us your code and what try before !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> ints = [5,3,6,1]
>>> sorted(ints, reverse=True)
[6, 5, 3, 1]
```

Or if they are already declared as separate variables

```
>>> x1 = 5
>>> x2 = 3
>>> x3 = 6
>>> x4 = 1
>>> sorted([x1, x2, x3, x4], reverse=True)
[6, 5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know how to reverse!